# In swift, how do I scale and position an SKSpriteNode to fit each iPhone?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, scaling

I'm having trouble understanding how I make my SKSpriteNode fit each iPhone. I have a background image and a separate chair image that needs to be in the same position and scalling for each iPhone. When I get it to look good on say the 6+ if I swap to a 5s its not in the correct position and isn't scaled for that iPhone. This is how I am currently scaling and positioning my SKSpriteNode.

```
chair.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.50, self.size.height * 0.35)
chair.setScale(0.50)
chair.zPosition = 1.0
self.addChild(Chair)
```

Comment: Need more information to give specific help, but things to look at: do you have multiple sizes for the images or are rescaling them yourself? what is the scaleMode of your scene? have you set anchor points for your SKSpriteNodes? Your code also contains an error, your 'addChild' is adding a class name rather than a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a problem of screen scale factors which are different from iPhone 5s (x2) to iPhone 6+ (x3). Simply multiply with screen factor you may solve the problem. The code (Swift) looks like bellow:

```
let screenScaleFactor = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
chair.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.50 * screenScaleFactor, self.size.height * 0.35 * screenScaleFactor)
chair.setScale(0.50 * screenScaleFactor)
chair.zPosition = 1.0
self.addChild(Chair)
```